# Class of an entity recognition

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I'm trying to start with **NLP** using Python using **nltk** or **spaCy**.

My question is, if I have the sentence,  `'Barack Obama was the former President of united states'`, How can I retrieve the word `president` to provide the class of the entity?

Comment: What is the logic for retrieving the word _"President"_? Are you retrieving the 6th word, or the first one starting with P, or the third one starting with a capital letter, or the first noun in the sentence, or what? Or to ask differently, what should be the result for e.g. _"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"_?

Comment: It is quite sensible to want to extract this information from a sentence, @zvone -- it just isn't what entity recognition does. (Also the OP tags were all over the place-- fixing)

Comment: Hello zvone, I'm trying to recognize the relation between a class and his entity and return the class.  If  I have  Fox is an Animal-> it should return Animal.  Knowing that the sentence could be more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I retrieve the word `president` [from "Obama was the former president"] to provide the class of the entity?

You cannot-- not with entity recognition, at least. *Entity recognition* can tell you that "Barack Obama" is a PERSON. To match the name to some information given about it in this sentence, you would need something like *relation extraction* which is a much more complex problem. The `nltk` doesn't provide a full solution out of the box, but can check [this nltk how-to](http://www.nltk.org/howto/relextract.html#relation-extraction) for a starter kit (including code).

Don't expect very smart performance! These kinds of functions are based on simple heuristics (example based on the link: assuming that we can recognize an ORGANIZATION `o` and a LOCATION `l` in a sentence, we might want to conclude that `o` is located in `l`).

Answer (score 1):

Bascially, alexis is right. The most reliable approaches (also deployed in research, I know) is dependency parsing of arguments. Then you can extract the relation of the copular verb (was) in order to relate "Barack Obama" to "president". A more markov-like approach would be OIE (open information extraction). A more linguistically interesting phenomenon is the usage of "former" here, inverting the truth conditionality of applying president to Obama, but this is probably not important in your model.